# How to override all Shapes in a specific area WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, drawing

Currently I am filling my MainWindow with a slightly transparent black:
[image]
But I want it to have a "hole" where this effect doesn't take place which should look like the following:[image]
So this needs to be done at runtime since the area which the hole represents is going to change multiple times while the program is running.

### What I thought I could do

1. So at first I thought I could just cut the area in the middle out
   like you could do with a Graphics object, but the slightly
   transparent black is nothing but a rectangle which is added as a child on a canvas which is currently done like this:

   ```
   var background = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle
               {
                   Fill = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(150, 0, 0, 0)),
                   Width = ScreenInfo.Width,
                   Height = ScreenInfo.Height
               };
               MainCanvas.Children.Add(background);
   ```

   But I couldn't fine any way to achieve this cut effect.
2. Creating 4 Rectangles which would look something like this:[image] but this way of doing it didn't seem to me as the most effecient way of achieving this.

Thanks for any kind of help!

Answer (score 1):

Create a CombinedGeometry by cutting a smaller square out of a larger one and then use that with a path. How you size it will depend on your application, a Viewbox will probably be good enough for most cases:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="Hello World!" FontSize="200" Foreground="Red" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center"/>

    <Viewbox Stretch="UniformToFill">
        <Path Fill="#C0000000">
            <Path.Data>
                <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Exclude">
                    <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,4,4" />
                    </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                    <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                        <RectangleGeometry x:Name="cutRect" Rect="1,1,2,2" />
                    </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                </CombinedGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Viewbox>

</Grid>
```

[image]

Then to change the size of the inner geometry you can either bind its Rect to a view model property or change it directly in code-behind:

```
cutRect.Rect = new Rect(1, 1, 1, 1);
```

Comment: This is pretty good, but I need to be able to set the position and width/height of the curRect in pixels is this somehow possible?

Comment: Sure, just get rid of the viewbox. You'll also need to set the dimensions of the first rectangle to match your client area.

Comment: I did remove the ViewBox and set the dimensions of the first rectangle, but how would I set the Width/Height and Position of the curRect by Pixel?

Comment: Just change what you're passing into the Rect structure, i.e. `cutRect.Rect = new Rect(x, y, w, h);`, where x/y/w/h are in pixels. And make sure you replace `Rect="0,0,4,4"` with `Rect="0,0,clientWidth,clientHeight"` as well.

Comment: Yeah I tried `cutRect.Rect = new Rect(x, y, w, h);` but this won't display the cutRect at all and everything is "dark".

Comment: And what values did you set the other rect to?

Comment: Also where are you setting these values? You need to set them at a point where you're sure that the window has been sized e.g. the `OnRenderSizeChanged` function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189386/discussion-between-twenty-and-mark-feldman).